# paradigm / pattern to solve dynamical function calling

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns, dynamic, polymorphism

I've been puzzling the last few days on trying to solve a problem in Javascript (typescript), and I'm unable to come to a solution that I feel comfortable with. So here is my scenario:

You have a class, that has a public function.. this public function will be called many thousands of times so performance is paramount. However, that function must be able to perform a dynamic task without the use of if statements or switching. For an example...

```
class foo {
    constructor() {

    }

    doWork1() {
        return 1 + 1;
    }

    doWork2() {
        return 5 + 5;
    }
}
```

Now any class MUST be able to call an agnostic doWork function, but without knowing if it should call doWork1, or doWork2. I have looked into mapping the functions to an enumerable, however performance tests show that to be a horrible approach, though it is scalable.

Therefore, the best solution I have come up with to date is thus:

```
class foo {

    public doWork:Function;

    constructor(fnFlag) {
        if(fnFlag === 1) {
            this.doWork = this.doWork1;
        } else if (fnFlag === 2) {
            this.doWork = this.doWork2;
        }
    }

    doWork1() {
        return 1 + 1;
    }

    doWork2() {
        return 5 + 5;
    }
}
```

In the code above, the public function doWork can be called by any class and will always point to the function it is initialised with. However, something just isn't sitting right with me and I don't feel like this is the best approach. I was contemplating passing the function in the constructor and assigning it there?

Any thoughts or advice on a pattern to solve an issue such as this would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *"but without knowing if it should call doWork1, or doWork2."* - But...it must know at some point which one it wants. In your example solution it *does* know at the point the constructor is called.

Comment: What determines which of the functions you want to call? And why do you think an if statement is not performant?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem to me... https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Replace `foo` with a factory - search for factory pattern - which instantiates e.g. a subclass of `foo` with the desired behavior. Dynamically swapping methods around makes stating class invariants and writing test cases much harder.

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the name of the function you want to call instead of an enum you can write it like this:

```
constructor(functionName) {
    this.doWork = this[functionName];
}
```

You can verify this with [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20foo%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20doWork%3AFunction%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(functionName)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.doWork%20%3D%20this%5BfunctionName%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doWork1()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%201%20%2B%201%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20doWork2()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%205%20%2B%205%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20test%20%3D%20new%20foo(%22doWork2%22)%0D%0Aalert(test.doWork())%3B).